# ChunkLoadError (timeout) and transferred over network size in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

I get ChunkLoadError (timeout).

On every reproduce of this error, "unloaded" file is different. In first reproduce it can be 23.js, in second 167.js and etc..

After two-three minutes my component breaks I see this message in the browser console:
[image]

This error reproduces only and only in Chrome(v114.0.5735.199 and others).
We can't reproduce this error on other browsers such Firefox, Safari or even Microsoft Edge.

Whenever I get the error I can see that bites **transferred over network** is so small.
[image: chunk when chrome does not load it]
**Why is only 391B? The file size is 2.8KB and in GZIP 1.6KB**

Lets compare the transferred over network size when this file is loading succesfully
[image: chunk when its loaded]
As you can see file size is 1.6kb when its successfully loaded.

And while waiting 2-3 minutes I can see this script tag in the end of `<head>`
[image]